# Parachain nodes become idle

Tags: parachain, kusama, parachain-collator, sync

The following nodes are Subsocial parachain nodes. We use `polkadot-v0.9.16` as our dependencies version. Gonna upgrade soon, but we need to solve the collators issues before.

Occasionally some of the nodes lose their peers or just stop syncing new blocks.

It looks like that on telemetry:
[image: Polkadot telemetry page screenshot]

---

After some explorations done, I saw no specific issues or errors on the "broken" node.

Here's the `RUST_LOG=runtime=debug` logs output:

```
2022-04-22 13:55:18.492  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Relaychain] ✨ Imported #12365417 (0x9848…0e07)    
2022-04-22 13:55:21.710  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Relaychain]  Idle (31 peers), best: #12365417 (0x9848…0e07), finalized #12365412 (0x7a5a…b415), ⬇ 808.5kiB/s ⬆ 481.4kiB/s    
2022-04-22 13:55:21.763  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Parachain] ⚙️  Syncing  0.0 bps, target=#368643 (5 peers), best: #368529 (0xb918…6868), finalized #368529 (0xb918…6868), ⬇ 1.6kiB/s ⬆ 1.6kiB/s    
2022-04-22 13:55:23.057  WARN tokio-runtime-worker parachain::collator-protocol: [Relaychain] No validators assigned to our core.
2022-04-22 13:55:24.380  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Relaychain] ✨ Imported #12365418 (0x6d22…522c)    
2022-04-22 13:55:24.391  WARN tokio-runtime-worker parachain::collator-protocol: [Relaychain] No validators assigned to our core.
2022-04-22 13:55:26.739  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Relaychain]  Idle (31 peers), best: #12365418 (0x6d22…522c), finalized #12365415 (0xd50a…0100), ⬇ 313.3kiB/s ⬆ 474.4kiB/s    
2022-04-22 13:55:26.765  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Parachain]  Idle (3 peers), best: #368529 (0xb918…6868), finalized #368529 (0xb918…6868), ⬇ 0.5kiB/s ⬆ 0.7kiB/s    
2022-04-22 13:55:26.949  WARN tokio-runtime-worker parachain::collator-protocol: [Relaychain] No validators assigned to our core.
2022-04-22 13:55:30.482  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Relaychain] ✨ Imported #12365419 (0xcada…7490)    
2022-04-22 13:55:31.754  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Relaychain]  Idle (31 peers), best: #12365419 (0xcada…7490), finalized #12365416 (0x0b97…f2bd), ⬇ 600.3kiB/s ⬆ 677.1kiB/s    
2022-04-22 13:55:31.766  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Parachain]  Idle (3 peers), best: #368529 (0xb918…6868), finalized #368529 (0xb918…6868), ⬇ 0.8kiB/s ⬆ 0.8kiB/s    
2022-04-22 13:55:36.518  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Relaychain] ✨ Imported #12365420 (0x5784…6499)    
2022-04-22 13:55:36.767  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Parachain]  Idle (3 peers), best: #368529 (0xb918…6868), finalized #368529 (0xb918…6868), ⬇ 0.5kiB/s ⬆ 0.6kiB/s    
2022-04-22 13:55:36.773  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Relaychain]  Idle (31 peers), best: #12365420 (0x5784…6499), finalized #12365416 (0x0b97…f2bd), ⬇ 204.3kiB/s ⬆ 286.7kiB/s    
2022-04-22 13:55:36.854  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Relaychain] ✨ Imported #12365420 (0x1313…b17d)
```

Sometimes we can see output like this as well:

```
2022-04-22 14:06:56.691  WARN tokio-runtime-worker parachain::runtime-api: [Relaychain] cannot query the runtime API version: UnknownBlock: State already discarded for BlockId::Hash(0x0914c22e73613d1fc07c37b81cc487f321dbfa4193cca6ad4b6675872118469b)
2022-04-22 14:06:56.695  WARN tokio-runtime-worker parachain::collator-protocol: [Relaychain] Failed to handle incoming network message err=NonFatal(Runtime(RuntimeRequest(NotSupported { runtime_api_name: "availability_cores" })))
```

Comment: There were a few recently fixed bugs in sync. Consider updating your dependency version.

Comment: Is this issue resolved? If so, please provide the solution :)

Comment: @DaanvanderPlas it was fixed by just upgrading. Though, it didn't fix the problem completely.
Still having some kind of "lags" after restarting nodes. It syncs to the head and then idles for a while. In a minute or less, it just syncs another ~10 blocks and continues working. Probably, upgrading to the latest version of deps for now may fix this one as well.